# Xamarin iOS Error initialized task IBTool

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I can't run any project for iOS in Xamarin, It shows me the following error "Error Initialized task IBTool: Not registered task IBToll", how I can resolve this error?
I use Xamarin Studio 5.9.4, XCode 5.0, Xamarin Ios 8.10.3.2 (Business Edition) and S.O Mac Os X 10.9.5
I hope you can help me
**UPGRADE**
=== Xamarin Studio ===

Version 5.9.4 (build 5)
Installation UUID: 616c0f77-e96a-4f5d-a6f7-c303c7e143c3
Runtime:
    Mono 4.0.2 ((detached/c99aa0c)
    GTK+ 2.24.23 (Raleigh theme)

```
Package version: 400020005
```

=== Xamarin.Android ===

Version: 5.1.4.16 (Business Edition)
Android SDK: /Users/student/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-mac_x86
    Supported Android versions:
        2.3   (API level 10)
        4.0.3 (API level 15)
Java SDK: /usr
java version "1.6.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_65-b14-462-11M4609)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.65-b04-462, mixed mode)

=== Xamarin Android Player ===

Not Installed

=== Apple Developer Tools ===

Xcode 5.0 (3332.22)
Build 5A1412

=== Xamarin.iOS ===

Version: 8.10.3.2 (Business Edition)
Hash: 8b265d6
Branch: master
Build date: 2015-06-30 15:19:13-0400

=== Xamarin.Mac ===

Not Installed

=== Build Information ===

Release ID: 509040005
Git revision: 8010a90f6e246b32364e3fb46ef2c9d1be9c9a2b
Build date: 2015-06-08 16:52:06-04
Xamarin addins: 7e93e9c3503f28770f23ce1b7eafd829919f18e8

=== Operating System ===

Mac OS X 10.9.5
Darwin Students-Mac.local 13.4.0 Darwin Kernel Version 13.4.0
    Sun Aug 17 19:50:11 PDT 2014
    root:xnu-2422.115.4~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64

Comment: You added most information but some bits are missing. The easiest way to get exact version information is to use the "Xamarin Studio" menu, "About Xamarin Studio" item, "Show Details" button and copy/paste the version informations (you can use the "Copy Information" button).

Comment: @poupou I added information about Xamarin Studio

Comment: Any specific reason to stick with Xcode 5 (almost 2 years old) ? I'm not 100% sure it's the reason but the rest of your versions are a very common combinaison across developers.